# ZSH Mac Mavericks $PATH variable is corrupt

Tags: macos, path, zsh

For some reason, I am getting all sorts of weird behavior in terminal, I think it's related to my $PATH variable.

If I run this command:

```
echo $PATH
```

it outputs this

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin...........
```

How do I reset it back to what it should be?

Comment: This probably belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your MAMP install has added something to your login script(s), which is adding itself to your PATH repeatedly.  Check your `~/.zshrc` file for suspicious lines.